# Linq Update - Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-excel

I'm using LinqToExcel along with C# to read data from a MS Excel spreadsheet and then update data records in my MS SQL database.

The Excel file has these headers: COURSE_ID, PROVIDER_COURSE_TITLE

My code is like this:

```
public class TestDataCourse
{
    [ExcelColumn("PROVIDER_COURSE_TITLE")]
    public string cTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////

string pathToExcelFile = @"C:\\O_COURSES.xlsx";
ConnexionExcel ConxObject = new ConnexionExcel(pathToExcelFile);

//read data from excel
var query1 = (from a in ConxObject.UrlConnexion.Worksheet<TestDataCourse>("O_COURSES")
                      select a).Take(2000).ToList();

//Get data from MS SQL database that need updated
var courses = _courseService.GetAllCoursesFromDB().Take(100).ToList();

int count = 0;

foreach (var course in courses)
{
     //Iterate through the excel doc and assign the 
     TestDataCourse fakeData = query1.Skip(count).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

     course.CourseTitle = fakeData.cTitle;

     count++;
}

_courseService.Save();
```

When I run this code I can see that it does update some of the records in my database, but as the code execution continues, I get a **Source Not Available** tab open within my Visual Studio and a **Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference**.

The null reference exception had me thinking that maybe there was some null data in the Excel doc, so I put this line of code into my for loop:

```
course.CourseTitle = fakeData == null ? "Course Test" : fakeData.cTitle;
```

But I still get the same problem.

Could anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question! I've set a break point in the code and stepped through over 50 times, each time I can see the data in my DB updating correctly, then when I continue the code execution by itself, falls over and I don't see the line which throws, all I get on the yellow screen of death is `[No relevant source lines]`

Comment: Did you check whether `course` was `null`?

Comment: Yes, I've also made a code validation to see if `course` is null, but even with that check, I still get the same error. Very difficult to debug because I don't want to step through 1000's of records.

Comment: Enable break on all exceptions. If execution reaches `Save()` then the problem is not before that.